# Slopes/angles and directions of 2D plane geometrical elements in 3D space

Tags: geometry

Let's approximate a part of the Earth surface using a mesh of 2D geometrical elements (e.g. triangles or rectangles, as in finite element method). Each element consists of vertices and edges. Since they are plane objects we can use Cartesian coordinates (x,y) for their locations (similar coordinates are used in the topographical maps together with geogr. lat. and long., here we do not consider the Earth curvature). Let X-axis points to the North, and Y-axis points to the East, the origin is somewhere in the space, but this is not important since we need distances . As an additional coordinate to each vertex we can assign its height above the mean sea level (z), the gravity force is in the opposite direction.

Having this information about each element (x, y, and z values) I have some questions.

1. How to calculate a general (mean) slope/angle of an element with respect to the XY-plane?
2. How to calculate particular slopes/angles of an element with respect to X-axis and with respect to Y-axis?
3. What is direction and orientation when it comes to 2D geometrical objects in 3D space and how actually to introduce a meaningful, computable and usable way to represent a direction?
4. Having question 3 how to compute the direction of the general slope of an element (but with respect to what)?
5. Having question 3 how to compute the directions of the particular slopes/angles of an element with respect to X-axis and with respect to Y-axis?
6. How to compute the area of the real element?
7. How to compute the area of the projected element over XY-palne?
8. Are there some ways in Mathematica, QGIS, Python, MATLAB to do all of this stuff correctly and efficiently and which are useful resources for reading and watching?

These computations are related to movement of fluid flow over an earth surface.

[Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LegV.png)

Comment: Who is the strange person who wants this well-formulated question to be closed ?

Comment: A general (not very operational) comment: you are at the heart of differential geometry : to which extend "working on a surface around a certain point $M$" is like "working on the tangent plane to $M$", and the **connection** ( a specialized term in fact) between two neighbours (or not) planes/triangular facets. For this last issue, you can use rotation matrices mapping at least approximately "landmarks" on facet $F_1$ to "landmarks" on facet $F_2$.